# OpenERP 7 - Display Product Cost in Bill of Materials (BoM)

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm a complete beginner with OpenErp7.
I would like to show the cost of products (product.standard_price?) in a Bill of Materials and the formula Product cost * item number

I've already tried

```
 'price': fields.related('product_id','product_tmpl_id.standard_price',type='float', size=64, relation="product.product", string="Price", store=True),
 'standardprice': fields.related('product_id','standard_price',type='float', size=64, relation="product.product", string="Standard Price", store=True),
```

but it's not working... I'd be grateful for any hint

Thanks in advance
Davide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first inherit mrp.bom and add a new field `'price_unit': fields.float('Unit Price')`

and redefine the `onchange_product_id` function as follows :

```
def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, name, context=None):
    if product_id:

        prod = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)

        return {'value': {'name': prod.name, 'product_uom': prod.uom_id.id, 'price_unit': prod.standard_price}}

    return {}
```